# How to check Java application logs installed in Openshift Pod

Tags: java, openshift

We are using Openshift infra. We have Dynatrace for metrics collection but not yet in good condition. Our Java Application on one of the Pod is not working. We use gradle build and have mentioned application log path in gradle config file. I want to see the application logs. How do i check the logs please?

Comment: If you were using recommended approach and logging to stdout/stderr, you would use ``oc logs`` on the pod name. If you aren't and are logging to container file system, you would need to use ``oc rsh`` to get into the pod, change to directory where logs written and tail them.

Comment: when you open the pod in openshift, don't you see logs tab?

Comment: kubectl exec -it <podname> /bin/bash . Now you are on bash prompt of pod. Go to folder where application logs exist and read them.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the way to check the logs as follows.

- If your log files output destination is `stdout`, then you can check the `oc logs` command.
- You can access the `pod` without running `application process` using `oc run`. Then access the pod using `oc rsh` for running the application process manually. You can check the log files saved pod after executing the application run script (e.g. `startup.sh` and so on).

For example that make the one-off pod run using `oc run`.

```
oc run <your_pod_nam> -i --tty --rm --image=<projectname_saved_image>/<you_want_to_run_java_app_image_name>
```